# PHP MySQL filter content value in related content

Tags: php, mysql

I search related title using this function :

```
$related = Access::FETCH("SELECT title, MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$DB_QUERY[0]['title']."') AS score
                FROM " . SONGS . "
                WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$DB_QUERY[0]['title']."') 
                ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5");
foreach($related as $row){
   echo $row['title'];
}
```

ie:

```
//search title clapton
 $DB_QUERY[0]['title'] = 'clapton'; 
//result
clapton // same title
eric clapton 
clapton song
clapton guitar
```

This worked for me But in result search and print same title + other title. how do can i find related title without show same title?!

Comment: what if you ditch the `title,` part? I think I am missing something, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
"SELECT title, MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$DB_QUERY[0]['title']."') AS score
            FROM " . SONGS . "
            WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$DB_QUERY[0]['title']."') 
            and title <> '".$DB_QUERY[0]['title']."'
            ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5"
```